# Using an input field in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this Ruby on Rails application where I open a modal, to make a new user. Now I want to listen to the forms in that modal with javascript, but for some reason it will not find my elements at all.

So lets say I have this function in .js:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#PWD1").on("keypress keyup keydown", function() 
    {
        console.log("Check");
    });
});
```

And this is how my input field looks like in the modal:

```
<input 
    class="PWD1" 
    id="user_password" 
    name="user[password]" 
    placeholder="Password..." 
    type="password">
```

And now when I type anything in that input field, my Check never gets printed into the console. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this:

```
$(".PWD1")
```

or with id:

```
$("#user_password")
```

You need to do a class selector this way.

---

You were referencing your selector with a **id** while that is a **class name**.

---

And also i am not sure if your modal is dynamically generated then you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent or `$(document)` itself.

```
$(document).on("keypress keyup keydown", ".PWD1", function() {
```

---

### Side Note:

As you are using `keypress keyup keydown` events so the callback function will trigger twice because of `keyup and keydown,keypress`.